# Add text to Order Totals block in Admin > Sales > Order > Reorder >View Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, reorder

How do i add some text on order totals in this section in picture ?  Magento 1

**Add text to Order Totals block in Admin > Sales > Order > Reorder >View**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\tab\info.phtml` you have `<div class="order-totals">`. This is the place where `order_totals` block is rendered.

**EDIT**
to add row under `subtotal`:
override : `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\create\totals\subtotal.phtml`.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, i did not find "order-totals" in the file that you have mentioned

Comment: weird... https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml at line 105 you should have this ```div```

Comment: Sir, this is exactly what i am asking for where are the above picture shows fields coming from this -         <div class="order-totals"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?></div>
?

Comment: <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?> render whole block (table). If you want some text in this place you can override this template.

Comment: Shall i override \app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\tab\info.phtml  ? Actually wanted to add another value below "Subtotal"

Comment: Check my update

Comment: Great thankyou, +1 for answer. Could you please tell me if we can get Basesubtotal in app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\create\totals\subtotal.phtml ?

Comment: ```$this->getTotal()->getData()['address']->getBaseSubtotal()``` this will give you ```base_subtotal```, but i am not sure if this is correct way to get this value. But it works :D. Glad i could help you

Comment: Thankyou i will check :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113566/discussion-between-hamendra-sunthwal-and-sebastiant).